# creating ODF files in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc, odf

I have a Java EE web application wherein I need to create an ODF file and fill it with submitted data.

How can I create and fill an ODF file using Java? Is there a library to use? I have noticed Apache POI, but I haven't found a well documented way to open and write an ODF using Java.

Comment: Did you try the [Apache ODF Toolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/)?

Comment: I have found JODReports, but i cant find an example explaining how to use it on a JSF web application. there is a demos (using spring, something that i won't would to understand !!). If someone can give me a hand ;)

Comment: The Apache ODF Toolkit no longer appears to exist.  A non-Apache [ODF Toolkit](https://odftoolkit.org/) ([github](https://github.com/tdf/odftoolkit)) - apparently by The Document Foundation / LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

[JODF](http://www.independentsoft.de/jodf) is another ODF library for Java and Android.

Comes with many [examples](http://www.independentsoft.de/jodf/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: i Want a "FREE" Solutions, i m working on a non profit institution !! i haven't a licence purshase plan.